# How to make intellij import scala project with scala 2.11.7 (as per build.sbt)?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm having problems with my project which I think are due to intellij pulling in a load of scala 2.10 libraries when it created/if I reimport my project.

How can I configure it to either read the version of scala from `build.sbt`, or manually configure it to compile with scala 2.11.7? I'm running intellij IDEA 14 with the latest updates and it always uses scala 2.10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have your Scala Version set in your build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

The rest works seemlessly. Enable "Auto-Import" in IDEA when creating the project.

Comment: I already had that. I think the problem was at first it was 2.10.4 and intellij pulled it in.

Comment: I found that, in a multi-project build, you need to define scalaVersion in _each one of your subproject's build.sbt files_. It's not enough to just set it at the 'root' level. Otherwise it will use the default (presumably 2.10.x)

Answer (score 0):

The 2.10 libraries are used by SBT itself. If you check the `Dependencies` tab for your modules, you shouldn't see them. If you do, you likely have an error in `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`.

Comment: Right I did have the scalaVersion set to 2.10.4 first of all and when I changed it intellij didn't evict the old libraries (I think that's what happened).